# How to implement Shared Memory in Windows Application and Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, shared-memory

I am making windows application and web application in .NET version 4.0. In that application i am sending request of data from .aspx page to windows application.The windows application has a collection of data.i want to send response to that request with proper data from collection.
       From web application i am requesting data for particular patient and for that  i am sending patientID  in query string. In windows application i have collection as

```
class StreamDataInfo
{        
    public string m_patientID { get; set; }
    public List<string> m_StreamData { get; set; }
}
```

From that collection i want to return data from m_StreamData list in response to that request.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your web application calls a Windows application? Where is the Windows application located? On the Server?

Comment: Why don't name the variables regularly? `PatientID` and `StreamData`?

Comment: @Heinzi :Yes windows application is on server.\

Comment: Have you considered putting the relevant code into a DLL and just referencing the DLL in your web application?

Comment: my windows application is continuously running on server.So how is it possible to use that DLL in web app?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at memory mapped files?

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/21/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand the architecture you have in mind...

But regarding to shared memory:

In windows this is implemented by means of "memory-mapped-files" - these can either be real file or "non-persistent" files.

In combination with a global `Mutex` you can implement a communication scheme between two or more processes/threads etc. on the same machine.

Some reference links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check the following options:

1. Host a WCF service in the Windows application that will expose your data. Have the web application request data from the WCF service.
2. Make the web application write the request to a file on a specified folder; the Windows application will poll this folder and then send the data to the web application (I'm not sure this will work fine because I do not have enough information about your architecture, but I would try to implement a WCF service in the web application for this)
3. Implement a WCF service that will directly expose data from the Windows application database or, if possible, directly access the Windows application database from the web application.